# Visualize SQL stored procedure relationships

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, visualization

While I can find a number of tools capable of producing visualizations of table relationships, are there tools for generating vizual representations of PostgreSQL stored procedures/functions?

I have a large set these at hand and need to understand how and when they connect, both to each other and to the tables available.

Suggestions on how to quickly get an overview?

Comment: What would you want to visualise? Which other functions they call, which tables they access, etc? If so, I'm not aware of any such tool. It'd be tricky with PostgreSQL where procedures may be written in any supported language.

Comment: I know about some tools used by some companies internally - typically only for plpgsql. In this moment these tools are not public. Some is planned to 9.4 - a deep checking is possible to use for collection info about used variables, tables, functions, ... You can write simple tool based on regular expressions and searching pg_proc table.

Comment: @Ringer. Yes, my main objective os to get an overview of how functions (sql code) call each other, and preferrably which tables are involved.

Comment: @Joshua: Did you eventually find a tool to visualize your stored procedures? You question is essentially the same as one of my questions, but mine got closed (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698564/visualizing-and-or-cross-compiling-40k-lines-of-t-sql-stored-procedures).

Comment: @Leif: Sadly I did not, I abandoned the idea to get this working as I first imagined. Ended up wading through the code myself.

Answer (score 1):

PowerDesigner visualizes functions' connections with tables that are used within them.

Comment: Isn't that thing for Sybase? OP posted a Postgres-related question.

Comment: You can use PD for postgres as well.